# Asynchronous value not binding on Angular 4 mat-select

Tags: angular, asynchronous, data-binding, material-design

I'm developing an Angular app with an API connection. Here's the code I have trouble with:

```
<mat-select [(value)]="this.item.name" (change)="onFamilySelected()">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let subfamily of subfamilies" [value]="subfamily">{{subfamily}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

When I'm on the `onFamilySelected()` function, `this.item.name` is undefined. Chrome's console shows it as evaluated later. `subfamilies` is a string array that comes asynchronously from an API (I retrieve it on `ngInit`), and it shows correctly on the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]` in `mat-select` like follows:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.item.name" (change)="onFamilySelected()">
```

Now in `onFamilySelected` you will get `this.item.name` successfully.